# SSIS packages unable to call Sp_ssis_addlogentry stored procedure

Tags: ssis

Some of my packages in the solution are unable to call Sp_SSIS_Addlogentry stored proecdure, due to which no logging is being captured for those packages. I am shocked to see why some other packages in the same solution are able to log their entries.

Any solution to rectify this? Anny suggestion ?

Comment: Package A runs and logs entries to sysdtslog90/sysssislog fine via the stored procedure sp_ssis_addlogentry. Package B runs and it is unable to call to stored proc and so no logging occurs. Is this accurate? If so, how do the two packages differ? What account executes A and what B? How are they run (SQL Agent, command line, BIDS, etc)? If Agent, is one using an operator? Do A and B log to the same server? If not, what version of sql server are they running?

Comment: @billinkc Actually I had created a solution under which I had created few packages.. almost same .. same permission.. same login. But when I moved these packages from one solution to other solution some of the packages stopped adding log entry but some of them are still working perfectly. Also, when I am copy pasting the same contect to new package it is working fine. I can not do copy paste like this because I have few very complex packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'sp_ssis_addlogentry' needs permission. Check your packages whether they have the EXECUTE permission or not. (have you got two or more connections in your SSIS solution? is it possible to try executing sp_ssis_addlogentry using DBA / sa login?)

Hope it helps, I had this problem some months ago and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you enable package logging to a SQL database. You should configure it to point at msdb, as that has all the required tables and stored procs, and then apply execute permissions on the necessary procs to the account you are executing the package as (typically a Proxy account if running from SQL Agent).

I'm not certain exactly which procs require permission, but I normally go with this:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [MyDomain\svcMy_SSIS_Proxy] FOR LOGIN [MyDomain\svcMy_SSIS_Proxy]
GO
CREATE ROLE [SSIS_Executor]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_addlogentry TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_checkexists TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_getfolder TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_getpackage TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_getpackageroles TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_listfolders TO [SSIS_Executor]
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_listpackages TO [SSIS_Executor]

ALTER ROLE [SSIS_Executor]
ADD MEMBER [MyDomain\svcMy_SSIS_Proxy]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikes answer works. I had the same situation where the proxy credential account did not have permissions to execute the stored procedure that adds logging to the logging database.

So, I only added

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_ssis_addlogentry TO [SSIS_Executor]
```

which was enough.

[image]